# powershell create folder and AD permission from array

Tags: powershell, security, permissions

I am have an Active Directory OU that contains a large number of security groups (course sections that contain students and teachers usernames)
I'd like to script via powershell that creates folders named using the security groups names then assign each security group the MODIFY permission to the corresponding folder.
Here is my script

```
#get all security groups
$sec_groups = Get-ADObject -SearchBase "ou=class,ou=Groups,ou=Colleague,dc=school,dc=edu" -LDAPFilter "(name=13_su*)" -ResultSetSize 10 | FT Name -HideTableHeaders 

ForEach ($sec_group in $sec_groups)
{
#create folder for each security group
$newPath = Join-Path -Path "\\server\classes" -childpath $sec_group
New-Item $newPath -type directory

#set permission for each folder
$acl = Get-Acl $newpath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("labadmins","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$sec_group","Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

Set-Acl $newPath $acl
}
```

It succeeds to create a folder for each security group but fails to set the `$sec_group` permission.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it written, **$sec_groups** is an array of formatted table entries. When you add the rule, you're trying to string-interpolate a table entry object and use it as the name of a group. To make **$sec_groups** an array of the names of the groups, change `FT Name -HideTableHeaders` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` in the second line:

```
$sec_groups = Get-ADObject -SearchBase "ou=class,ou=Groups,ou=Colleague,dc=school,dc=edu" -LDAPFilter "(name=13_su*)" -ResultSetSize 10 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

However, since what you're doing to create the folders is working (implying that **$sec_group** on its own does convert cleanly to a string when used as an argument to **-Childpath**), you might be able to get away with just getting rid of the quotes around **$sec_group** when setting the rule:

```
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($sec_group,"Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
```

The first one is a better habit, though.

In fact, you don't need to quote **$sec_group** in either case. It's redundant to string-interpolate a string variable by itself.

Comment: If it works, please click the check mark on the left to accept the answer. I'm over 99% certain that it will. Your syntax for modifying the permissions is correct, the only problem I see is that "$sec_group" doesn't evaluate to the names of the groups.

Comment: i get this error

AddAccessRule : Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

+ $acl.AddAccessRule <<<< ($rule)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Oh, right - the domain name is missing. Replace `$sec_group` in the **New-Object** call with `"school.edu\$sec_group"`. If **labadmins** is also a domain group, it should be `"school.com\labadmins"` in the first **New-Object** call. (You can also use the NetBIOS name of the domain, of course.)

Comment: Adi, I tried that and in either case, the "labadmins" work fine but not the other groups. I noticed that the "Pre-2000" name has a string of characters starts with $ while "labadmins" has "labadmins" also in the pre2000 name. does that affect anything?